# CDF , confusion

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If $F(x) = 1/3$ for $0 \leq x  < 2/5$ and $3/4$ for $2/5 \leq x < 4/5$, and $F(x) = 1$ for $x \geq 4/5$, and $X$ has $\mathrm{CDF} = F$, I want to compute $P(X > 4/5)$ and $P(X = 2/5)$.

I suspect that I'm missing something important here, because I wanted to answer that for $X$ with $\mathrm{CDF} = F$,  $P(X > 4/5) = 1$ since $F(x)$ is defined as being equal to $1$ for $x \geq 4/5$. However, apparantly the answer is $0$. I'm equally confused about $P(X = 2/5)$, since I thought $P(X = x) = 0$ for continuous functions, but the answer is $1/4$.

Can anyone help to explain?

Comment: According to your definition of $F$ we have $F(1)=\frac34$ **and** $F(1)=1$, so something is wrong.

Comment: You are right, I didn't even notice that. Now I'm more confused.

Comment: I suspect that $5/4$ must be changed into $4/5$.

Comment: I changed it, because I think you are right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your first question:

Since:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X>x)=\mathbb{P}(\{X\leq x\}^c)=1-\mathbb{P}(X\leq x)=1-\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}F(x+\varepsilon)
$$
Since $F(\frac{4}{5})=1$, the result follows.

For your second question:
$$
\mathbb{P}(X=x)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\mathbb{P}(x-\varepsilon<X<x+\varepsilon)=
$$
$$
=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(\mathbb{P}(X<x+\varepsilon)-\mathbb{P}(X<x-\varepsilon)\right)=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0}\left(F(x+\varepsilon)-F(x-\varepsilon)\right)
$$
And in this case
$$
F\left(\frac{2}{5}+\varepsilon\right)=\frac{3}{4}\qquad F\left(\frac{2}{5}-\varepsilon\right)=\frac{1}{3}
$$
Thus
$$
\mathbb{P}\left(X=\frac{2}{5}\right)=\frac{3}{4}-\frac{1}{3}=\frac{5}{12}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

$P(X>\frac45)=1-P(X\leq\frac45)=1-F(\frac45)$

$P(X=\frac25)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0+}P\left(\frac{2}{5}-\epsilon<X\leq\frac{2}{5}\right)=\lim_{\epsilon\rightarrow0+}\left[F\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)-F\left(\frac{2}{5}-\epsilon\right)\right]$

Answer (score 0):

You actually have a discrete distribution with

- $\Pr(X=0)=\frac13$ assuming $F(x)=0$ for $x \lt 0$
- $\Pr(X=\frac25)=\frac34-\frac13=\frac5{12}$
- $\Pr(X=\frac45)=1-\frac34=\frac14$

and $\Pr(X=x)=0$ for all other $x$.

Comment: Why in heaven's name was I so sure this was a continuous distribution? I seriously need to take a break from studying. My brain has turned into pudding.